# Changing breed designation of "Pit Mix"

Tags: dogs, legal

I recently adopted a dog from an animal rescue society. While she was listed as a mix of breed X on the rescue society's website, her veterinary paperwork shows "Pit Mix" as her predominant breed.

While she has a few features that might suggest pitbull, to my untrained eye, she looks more like breed X. For example, she has a much longer snout than any pitbulls I've seen.

As far as I've read, identifying mixed breeds by eye is subject to a lot of error anyway. The "Pit Mix" designation limits where we can rent and even what towns we can live in, so we'd like to try to change it. Let me just add that she has a very calm and gentle temperament and that we plan to go to professional training with her.  We live in a Midwestern US state.

Does anyone have experience changing a dog's breed designation? Is it simply a matter of finding a sympathetic veterinarian?

Comment: And just what is Breed X.  Could you post a picture?

Answer (score 1):

When clients register with us they tell us what the breed is suppose to be, it's subjective unless you do DNA testing (which is cheap where I work in Canada).
Sometimes we end up changing it because we simply do not see the breed that the owner mentions (this is for owners who have not seen their dogs parents).

Going for a check-up at a different veterinarian and mentioning what breed you think she is, they might not change it and that will be on her new records.

Best way to know what mixture of breeds you have is by doing DNA testing (we send off blood samples). Though it may not end up in your favor if she does have some pitty in there.